# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous when using PyBrain

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

I'm aware that there's numerous neural networks packages available for Python, so I'm not sure where to start. I started off with Pybrain, but its documentation isn't clear to follow.

I'm working on a training set with 100000 rows and 6 features with an outcome variable that only takes on binary values

```
   Outcome      A_PCT     A_XYZ       A_ABC    B_PCT   B_XYZ   B_ABC
   1            0.412      16         288      0.562      16   163
   0            0.750      15         127      0.844      2    10
   0            0.909      1           1       0.700      16   119
   1            0.633      11         23       0.656      6    32
   1            0.600      11         67       0.719      6    14
   0            0.758      5           17       0.636     12    55
```

I wasn't sure what to use for the input and target size for

```
ds = ClassificationDataSet(6,nb_classes=2, class_labels=['1','0'])
ds.setField( 'input', trainData[features] )
fnn = buildNetwork( 6, 5, 6, outclass=SoftmaxLayer )
trainer = BackpropTrainer( fnn, dataset=trainData, momentum=0.1, verbose=True, weightdecay=0.01)
trainer.trainUntilConvergence( verbose = True, validationProportion = 0.15, maxEpochs = 1000, continueEpochs = 10 )
predicted = net.activateOnDataset( ds )
```

However, I get the error `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` at the line

```
trainer = BackpropTrainer( fnn, dataset=trainData, momentum=0.1, verbose=True, weightdecay=0.01)
```

what does this mean? Are there better neural network packages for beginners?